# Reading arbitrarily long lines from a file that is redirected as input

Tags: c, strings, io

So I have a file with a list of dates that are to be redirected as input to stdin and what the program does is it searches for valid dates, appends them to the output file and then appends all the dates in the input file to the output file. In other words, at the end of the program there would be a list of all the valid dates in the output file and list of all the dates that were in the input file. An important command line argument is the number of entries to search for. 0 here is the default case where we look through the entire input file. Any value greater than 0 represent the number of entries we have to look at. If we find one that is invalid, we skip it.

**Command Example:** ./program < input.txt 0 > output.txt

Here are all the relevant functions.

**getDates Function**

```
char ** getDates(char **lines, size_t *numOfLines, size_t *lineMax, int numOfEntries)
{
    char *strDate = NULL;
    int allEntries = FALSE, errorStatus = FALSE; // errorStatus is so I can report memory failures.


    if(numOfEntries == 0) 
    {
        allEntries = TRUE; // A flag for the default case zero.
    }

    while((strDate = readLine(stdin, &errorStatus)) != NULL)
    {
        if(numOfEntries >= 0 || allEntries)
        {
            if(checkDate(strDate))
            {
                fputs(strDate, stdout);
            }

            numOfEntries--;
        }

        /* 
       Keep a record of how many lines we have process. 
       We will need this variable when we decide to print 
       everything that we have in the variable lines. 
        */
        lines[*numOfLines] = strDate;
        (*numOfLines)++; 

        if((*numOfLines) == (*lineMax))
        {
            errorStatus = expand(lines, lineMax); // try to expand.

            if(errorStatus == MEMFAILURE)
            {
                fprintf (stderr,"Error, couldn't allocate any more memory.");
                return NULL;
            }
        }
    }

    if(errorStatus == MEMFAILURE)
    {
        fprintf (stderr,"Error, couldn't allocate any more memory.");
        return NULL;
    }

    if(ferror(stdin))
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"Error, couldn't completely process the entire file.\n");
        return NULL;
    }

    if(strDate != NULL)
    {
        free(strDate);
    }

    return lines;
}
```

**readLine Function**

```
char *readLine(FILE *stream, int *errorStatus)
{
    size_t size = 0;
    char *buffer = NULL;
    char *newLineFound = NULL;

    do
    {
        char *temp = realloc(buffer, size + BUFSIZ); // BUFSIZE is a define constant in the stdio library.

        if(!temp)
        {
            free(buffer);
            *errorStatus = MEMFAILURE; // an enum constant to record our error.
            return NULL;
        }

        buffer = temp;

        // One small problem. If there is no new line at the end of the file. it won't add whatever contents is there.
        if(!fgets(buffer + size, BUFSIZ, stream))
        {
            free(buffer);
            return NULL;
        }

        newLineFound = strchr(buffer + size, '\n');

    }
    while(!newLineFound && (size += BUFSIZ - 1)); // this is to simply update size at the same time that we don't find a newline.

    return buffer;
}
```

**expand Function**

```
int expand(char **lines, size_t *lineMax)
{
    char **tmp = realloc (lines, (*lineMax) * 2 * sizeof(*lines));

    if(!tmp)
    {
        return MEMFAILURE;
    }

    lines = tmp;
    (*lineMax) *= 2; // Update the size

    return SUCCESS;
}
```

- What can I do to reduce my code as I feel that it is getting too bloated.
- What did I forget to do, what didn't I do right and what did I do that was unnecessary.
- Performance tips are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

**What can I do to reduce my code as I feel that it is getting too bloated.**

1. No need for test.  Just call `free();`.  It handles `free(NULL);`

   ```
   // if(strDate != NULL) {
   //  free(strDate);
   // }
   free(strDate);
   ```
2. Minor: Style: I found the vertical spacing excessive creating challenges seeing the overall flow.  YMMV

**What did I forget to do, what didn't I do right and what did I do that was unnecessary.**

1. Certain functional error, `lines` is assigned a value that is not used.  Need to pass a "reference".

   ```
   int expand(char **lines, size_t *lineMax) {
     char **tmp = realloc (...);
     ...
     lines = tmp;
     ... 
     return SUCCESS;
   }
   ```
2. Functional error (possible part of your "One small problem." comment).  If `fgets()` returns `NULL`, code should only dispose of the buffer if this is the *first* `fgets()` in `readLine()`.  Or: if the reason for `NULL` is due to `ferror()` and not `feof()`.
3. Functional corner case: `strchr(buffer` searches the buffer and can get fooled by `fgets()` reading a null charter and then a end-of-line such as `"\0\n"`.  No true way to solve this and still use `fgets()`.

   ```
     newLineFound = strchr(buffer + size, '\n');
   }
   while(!newLineFound && (size += BUFSIZ - 1));
   ```
4. Minor: Format to the presentation width.

   ```
   // avoid
   int allEntries = FALSE, errorStatus = FALSE; // errorStatus is so I can report memory failures.

   // better
   // errorStatus is so I can report memory failures.
   int allEntries = FALSE, errorStatus = FALSE;
   ```
5. Use `bool`.  It is standard and well defined.

   ```
   #include <stdbool.h>
   // int allEntries = FALSE, errorStatus = FALSE;
   bool allEntries = false, errorStatus = false;
   ```
6. Not all `stderr` are unbuffered. Suggest appending `'\n'` to your print to insure timely display.  Note either call below may make the same code with smart compilers.  2nd has the advantage of no problems with `'%'`

   ```
   // fprintf (stderr,"Error, couldn't allocate any more memory.");
   fprintf(stderr,"Error, couldn't allocate any more memory.\n");
   // or 
   fputs("Error, couldn't allocate any more memory.\n", stderr);
   ```
7. Confusing code: simplification suggestion

   ```
   // char **tmp = realloc (lines, (*lineMax) * 2 * sizeof(*lines));
   size_t newsize = *lineMax * 2;
   void *tmp = realloc (lines, sizeof(*lines) * newsize);
   ....
   *lineMax = newsize;
   ```
8. Lost memory

   ```
   char **tmp = realloc (lines, (*lineMax) * 2 * sizeof(*lines));

   if(!tmp) {

     // Add
     free(lines);

     return MEMFAILURE;
   }
   ```
9. Functional corner case:  If `*lineMax` could *ever* be 0.  Returning `NULL` is OK when the size of 0 and not a `MEMFAILURE`.

   ```
   char **tmp = realloc (lines, (*lineMax) * 2 * sizeof(*lines));

   // if(!tmp) {
   if(!tmp && *lineMax) {
         return MEMFAILURE;
   }
   ```
10. Functional: To be more resilient, check size before using the array.  `getDates()` does not control input of the `count/size`.

    ```
    // move here
    if((*numOfLines) >= (*lineMax)) ...

    lines[*numOfLines] = strDate;
    (*numOfLines)++; 

    // if((*numOfLines) == (*lineMax)) ...
    ```

**Performance tips are welcome.**

1. I/O is often a candidate for speed improvements.  For this code, if there is no other calls to `stdin`, I would use `fread()` and then process the lines  myself, reading large blocks.
2. On systems that use `'\n'` translation, improvement can be had by reading in binary mode.
3. When a file ends without a final `'\n'`, code is probably faster  appending one, insuring the rest of code does not have to check for that expectation.

GTG

Comment: In number 8, why are you freeing lines and not temp? In number 7, why did you change temp to single pointer instead of a double pointer?

Comment: @Luis Averhoff  #8: `free(temp)` is the same as the uneeded `free(NULL);`.  `free(lines)` because the code no longer has access to `lines`.  IAC, `expand()1` needs re-work per #1.

Comment: @Luis Averhoff #7 `tmp` is a `void *` - the universal "we don't care about the type" pointer.  It is just a code simplification. - minor bloat reduction.

Comment: Well I could make line a triple pointer(you said I need to pass a reference) but that would degrade code readability. So I guess I could just make expand return NULL if realloc fails or lines if it succeeds.

Comment: For number 9, how can *lineMax ever be zero if I initially set it some value at the start of the program.

Comment: You said that we free(lines) because the code no longer has access to lines. How does realloc failing and returning a null pointer to temp means that that the code no longer has access to lines? I thought the whole reason we used a temporary variable was so that we can preserve the connection to the memory block that line is pointing to .

Comment: @Luis Averhoff Think about the call `errorStatus = expand(lines, lineMax);`.  As `expand()` changes its internal variable `lines` with `lines = tmp;`, that has no effect on the calling code's `lines`.

Comment: @Luis Averhoff  #9: `*lineMax` can be `0` if the calling code sets it to 0.  `int main(void) { char **lns = NULL;  size_t sz = 0;  printf("%d\n", expand(lns, &sz); }`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37578/discussion-between-chux-and-luis-averhoff).